# ThreeJS world to local coordinate

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js, linear-algebra

I'm having 2 meshes: a cube (A) and a sphere (B), both separated and have no parent. I'm making a tool where I use the sphere position in relation to the cube's face to extrude the cube. I'm using Transform Controls to control the sphere helper.

I'm drawing a line from the vertex of the box to the sphere position. My problem is when the cube rotates, I need to figure out the coordinate of the sphere in the cube's local coordinate, so I know which face of the cube to extrude out. Similar to this gif here:

[image: Text]

I tried worldToLocal in the 'change' event of Transform Control (m_box is the cube, m_mesh is the sphere helper, and m_prevPos is the cached previous position of the sphere helper to figure out the direction of change):

```
const localPrev: Vector3 = this.m_box.worldToLocal(this.m_prevPos);
const localNew: Vector3 = this.m_box.worldToLocal(this.m_mesh.position);
const localDir = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
localDir.subVectors(localNew, localPrev);
```

But the coordinate from worldToLocal is the same as the sphere's world coordinate, not the position in relation to the rotated cube.

What I'm trying to say is, when the cube is not rotated, the sphere world position and local position will be the same. But as the cube rotates, the local coordinate (basis vector) should change, so the world and local position of the sphere should be different. Like this example:

[image]

[image]

So the point in red should still be at (0, 2) position on the cube, but in the world, it will be (-2, 1) in the world coordinate. I'm trying to get the (0, 2) position. Also, when the point in red moves, the translation vector would also be in the cube's local coordinate (say (1, 0) means moves along the X axis of the cube, factored in the cube rotation, not the world's X axis). How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ThreeJS movement between world to local coordinate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67632008/threejs-movement-between-world-to-local-coordinate)

Comment: No they are not the same question